# how to set profiles using parallel_tests gem

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rake, jruby

How do I specify a cucumber profile when using the parallel tests gem?

If I were to launch cucumber from the command line (using Jruby) I would do

```
Jruby -S cucumber -p profile_name
```

and using rake tasks I would set the tasks profile `t.profle=myprofile` and then execute using `rake mytask`

so when using parallel_tests I launch the tests using the built in rake tasks associated with the gem : `rake parallel:features` is there any way to pass in `t.profile` argument into the rake task on execution?

What i would like to do is something along the lines of

`rake parallel:features[4] t.profile=myprofile`

Comment: Theoretically the following should work: rake parallel:features -- -o '-p myprofile'
For me it doesn't work though... I'll edit the cucumber.yml every time and use kross' solution until someone can help us.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be useful, but in the `cucumber.yml`, you can just add a `parallel:` profile and it will get picked up automatically.  [You can specify one on command line](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/commit/8a38f02b65045d72bf50be5fb5c6b179329db061) but I didn't bother trying to figure it out because I don't really have the need to switch profiles.